# Partly covered personal info on User Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-profile

Go to your Arqade profile (Not Arqade meta) and click less info. Then click more info. This is the result.

[image: User profile showing partly covered name]

Notice the blank part?

[image: Cropped, partly-covered user info]

The blank part which covered my real name?

Sometimes this bug does not appear.

Using OS X Mavericks, Safari, 100% zoom.

Comment: So is the problem that "real name" is invisible after re-expanding your info? Can you say what OS/browser you're using?

Comment: @StrixVaria Somehow something blocked it. Highlighting the covered makes it reappears.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in Firefox 36.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The User Profile page went through a major redesign a few years ago, and this bug was inadvertently addressed by that overhaul; removing the less info/more info functionality entirely.